# I have a django app running on a cpanel's subdomain. The challenge I am experiencing is I have ajax buttons that are not returning data

Tags: django, ajax, deployment, subdomain, cpanel

**This is in my views.py**
`

```
def minuscreditcart(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        product_id = request.GET['prod_id']
        print(product_id)
        print("GET MINUS {}", product_id)
        c = CreditCart.objects.get(Q(ordered=False) & Q(product=product_id) & Q(customer=Customer.objects.get(user_account=request.user)))
        if c.quantity <=1:
            pass
        else:
            c.quantity -= 1
            c.save()
        cart = CreditCart.objects.filter(Q(customer=Customer.objects.get(user_account=request.user)) & Q(ordered=False))
        creditApp = Credit_Facility_Application.objects.get(Q(disclaimer=False) &Q(customer=Customer.objects.get(user_account=request.user)))
        instal = Instalment.objects.get(application_form=creditApp)
        amount = 0
        period = instal.period
        deposit = instal.deposit
        period = int(period)
        customer = Customer.objects.get(user_account=request.user)

        try:
            employment = Employment_detail.objects.get(customer=customer)
            employmentInfo = EmploymentForm(instance=employment)
            net_salary = employment.net_salary
            credit_limit = net_salary * 0.25
            creditlimit = credit_limit
        except:
            credit_limit = False
            employmentInfo = EmploymentForm()

        admincharge = 0.03 ;
        mothlycharge = 0.08; 
        ssbcharge = 0.05;
        for p in cart:
            value = p.quantity * p.product.discount_price
            amount = amount + value
        totalamount = amount
        
        balance = (1 + admincharge) * totalamount;
        depositlimit = int(balance * 0.3);
        balance = balance - deposit;

        totalmonthlycharges = mothlycharge * period;

        aftermonthlycharges = (1 + totalmonthlycharges) * balance;

        totalamount = ((1 + ssbcharge) * aftermonthlycharges)
        instalment = (totalamount / period)

                myinstalment = round(instalment, 2)
        data = {
            'quantity':c.quantity,
            'amount':amount,
            'totalamount':totalamount,
                'myinstalment':myinstalment,
            'period':period,
            'depositlimit':depositlimit,
            }
        return JsonResponse(data)
```

**This is the respective ajax code**

```
$('.minus-credit-cart').click(function(){
    var id=$(this).attr("pid").toString();
    var eml=this.parentNode.children[2];

    $.ajax({
        type:"GET",
        url:"/minus-credit-cart",
        data:{
            prod_id:id

        },
        success:function(data){
            eml.innerText=data.quantity 
            document.getElementById("amount").innerText=data.amount;
            document.getElementById("totalamount").innerText=data.myinstalment;
            document.getElementById("period").innerText=data.period;
            document.getElementById("depositamount").innerText = data.depositlimit;
            document.getElementById("depo").innerText = "Deposit Limit";
            mydep = document.getElementById("deposit");
            mydep.setAttribute("min", data.depositlimit);
            mydeplim = document.getElementById("depositlimit");
            mydeplim.setAttribute("value", data.depositlimit);
        }
    })
})
```

I expected my code to subtract an item from the credit cart when a minus button is clicked, the same should happen with respect to the plus button.

In development environment the code was running smooth and fine.
These buttons are hitting the database using the GET method.
The results should be returned after committing to the database.